# Is is possible to create custom shapes with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-processing, fluent-ffmpeg

I am trying to create a xstack layout with ffmpeg commands and from what I have seen online it is only possible to create rectangles with all the videos merge them into one video. However, I am trying to create a layout with custom shapes with X and Y coordinates.

Example:
[image: Example of the three input videos with custom layout and shapes]

Would this be possible with ffmpeg or do I need another library or open source code base to create this?

Comment: Is the video perspective skewed to this shape, or is it just the shape of the mask?

Comment: The shapes would be masks for different videos. Therefore in each shape there would be a video playing.